# How to create a state list drawable for my ListView items?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, selector

I have a custom ListView selector which draws on top of a ListView. It works fine, but I want the text inside of the listview to turn white. How can I do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/stocks_gradient" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/swipeview_selected_gradient" />
  <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/swipeview_selected_gradient" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply specific color or selector to each list item.

I have something like this (abreviated)

layout/dash_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             style="@style/DashboardListItem">
   ... Your text components etc ....
```

color/dashboard_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@color/dash_border_color" />
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@color/dash_border_color" />
</selector>
```

values/style.xml

```
 <style name="DashboardListItem">
        <item name="android:background">@color/dashboard_selector</item>
 </style>
```

You probably will need to play with it to figure where exactly apply things. It can probably be simplified. Anyway, it's just a direction since I don't know your specific requirements.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? How can I add a selector to each list item?

Comment: You define list items layouts via adapter, right? In any case, you would need to inflate some layout for list items. This layout would be the one that contains your text. So to alter color of this text, you would need to apply style or selector to this specific layout or components inside it. If text look does not have to change on clicks or focus, you can just set `textColor`. If it must react to the state then you would need a selector. I will see if I find some example.

Comment: Ok, added some example. May be it will help.

Comment: I am already doing this in my app. The selector appears fine, but the text inside the listviewitem does not change. I want the text font color to change to white when it is highlighted.

Comment: Did you try to apply selector to TextView directly? Also since it takes textColor attribute, it may be possible to use `textColor="@color/selector"`. Also note that my selector lives in 'color' not 'drawable'.