# StateDrawable for ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have an astonishingly simple list (inside a list fragment) . I need to change the color of the drawable of the row which is pressed upon .

I know statedrawables are the way to do that , but I am new to this and I got really confused as I went through the other answers detailing this subject.

If you could provide some concrete pointers in the right direction , it would be great.

It is just a simple list , that contains ten rows. Whatever row I press , I need to change its drawable .

Comment: see the default list view selector xml file (list_selector_background.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Have you read these articles?

[How to create a state list drawable for my ListView items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146333/how-to-create-a-state-list-drawable-for-my-listview-items)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html