# How to change list Item appearance on item click.

Tags: java, android, xml

In my application i have horizontal list view. On Item select I want to change that selected Item background color and it's text view color. i have figured out that part. But how to reset background color and text view color of previously selected item. here's my adapter class.

```
public class DateRangeListViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DateRangeListViewAdapter.ContentViewHolder>  {

private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<String> data;
private Context context;
private int dataType;
private int previousSelectedPosition;
private static final int DATE_TYPE = 1;
private static final int STATUS_TYPE = 2;

public DateRangeListViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> data, Context context,int dataType) {
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
    this.dataType = dataType;
    inflater  = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    previousSelectedPosition = -1;
}

public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

@Override
public ContentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_date_range_list_item,parent,false);
    return new ContentViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContentViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String name = data.get(position);
    holder.dateText.setText(name);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


public class ContentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private FrameLayout main;
    private TextView dateText;

    public ContentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        main = (FrameLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        dateText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Selected item color change
        main.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.date_range_selected_item_background));
        dateText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorPrimary));

        if(itemClickListener!=null){
            itemClickListener.onItemClick(v,this.getLayoutPosition(),dataType,getOldPosition());
        }
    }
}

public interface ItemClickListener{
    public void onItemClick(View v, int position,int dataType,int oldPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should indicate in your code where the background needs to be reset.

Comment: on Item click look inside `ContentViewHolder` view holder class

Comment: Call `notifyDataSetChanged` before setting the background and text color

Comment: That's not working. I think you haven't reed the question correctly the code I posted is working. I want to reset item appearance back to normal when item is selected for second time.

Comment: Use state-list drawable as background for `custom_date_range_list_item` .[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146333/how-to-create-a-state-list-drawable-for-my-listview-items).

Comment: @Adithya can It also chage text view color at the same time please post full solution.

Comment: No. you can change `textColor` inside 'onClick` or make a similar state-list drawable for `TextView` with different colors for `state_pressed` and other states.

Comment: Do you want to change colors of multiple selected items or just change background and textColor of one item when its clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want to make good use of your int flag, `previousSelectedPosition`, to keep track of the list item's position that was clicked, invoke `notifyDataSetChanged()`, and then set the flag as part of a conditional statement within `onBindViewHolder()` to update ViewHolder's views accordingly as they continuously get binded. Try the following changes:

ViewHolder's onClick():

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (itemClickListener!=null) {
        previousSelectedPosition = getAdapterPosition();

        notifyDataSetChanged();

        itemClickListener.onItemClick(v,this.getLayoutPosition(),dataType,getOldPosition());
    }
}
```

RecyclerView.Adapter's onBindViewHolder():

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContentViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String name = data.get(position);
    holder.dateText.setText(name);

    if (previousSelectedPosition == position) {
        main.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.date_range_selected_item_background));
        dateText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorPrimary));
    } else {
        // TODO: Configure the FrameLayout and TextView here for initial runtime as well as back to default
    }
}
```

... and yes, make sure to keep `previousSelectedPosition` initialized as -1 for the initial runtime just so the condition in `onBindViewHolder()` wouldn't matter **until** the flag updates (after a list item is clicked, that is).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's working A little doubt, when calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't it going to re draw entire list view ? If yes isn't this bad for performance.I thought there might be a way to find list view item by position and change that only to default design when clicking second item.

Comment: @ChathurangaShanJayarathna notifyDataSetChanged() only updates the list items that are currently on-screen as opposed to rebuilding the whole list, so no, it's not expensive in memory. As for your issue, I'm sure there's a way, but it's good practice to use my approach since updating the UI of an individual row of a list consisting of many list items (especially when new rows are inserted) of say, 100 rows off-screen, leads to a bug where "every other" list item is updated as well. This tutorial video may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ntrf-sWSrNs

Answer (score 0):

Your `OnClickListener` does not work perfectly. You just need to implements your `ViewHolder` from you "ItemClickListener" interface. And add this line in `onCreateViewHolder` :

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_date_range_list_item,parent,false);
ContentViewHolder cVh =  ContentViewHolder(view);view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            cVh.onItemClick(v,this.getLayoutPosition(),cVh .dataType,cVh .getOldPosition());

        }
    });return cVh
```